# matplotlibrc has no effect on the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, configuration, configuration-files

I want to change the look of my default plots in Python, so I created the file *matplotlibrc* in the current working directory (Windows 7). The file gets loaded -

```
import matplotlib as mp
print('Config. file loaded from:', mp.matplotlib_fname())
```

returns

```
Config. file loaded from: C:\Users\mato\Documents\Python_Scripts\matplotlibrc
```

however, the plot is unaffected.

The simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x)
```

with the *matplotlibrc* file that looks like this:

```
lines.linestyle   : --
axes.grid         : True
```

yields the plot with the solid line and no grid in the plot. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you edit the matplotlibrc template from http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html (or your system folder)? It looks like this always starts by specifying a default backend with the line `backend  : [DEFAULT]`. May be why it's ignoring your local file...

Comment: I started by editing the template file, but for the simplicity switched to the 2-liner shown above. The current working directory is the first place where the python looks for the _matplotlibrc_.

Comment: Without specifying a backend in `matplotlibrc` I don't get a plot at all (on linux). With your `matplotlibrc` file, the variables `mp.rcParams['lines.linestyle']` and `mp.rcParams['axes.grid']` are correctly specified and this works as expected... If you set the values within your code (e.g. `mp.rcParams['lines.linestyle']='--'`) does this changed the linestyle as expected? Could be a problem with the backend plotting or maybe the options are overwritten somehow.

Comment: If I insert _plt.rcParams['axes.grid']=True
plt.rcParams['lines.linestyle']='--'_ in the code, it works as expected

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution was to simply uncomment the commands.(remove the "#" before the parameter you want to be changed)
 Oh man!

Comment: Please elucidate more and be specific with the code change.